# How would I find a value from a json file that has been dumped before?

Tags: python, json

I might not be asking this correctly, since I'm quite new to json. I have this code:

```
        data = {
            "temp1": [
                {"temp2": "!"},
                {"temp3": "123"}
            ]
        }
        with open("./Config/test.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=1)
        with open("./Config/test.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        print(data["temp1"]["temp2"])
```

There will be more dictionaries like this with their unique id. The id is now labeled as temp1. How can I return the temp2 or temp3 value, without returning the whole json?

Comment: There's no `guildid` key in `data`.

Comment: There's no `temp` key, it's `temp1`.

Comment: `data["temp1"]["temp2"]` will return `"!"`

Comment: Is `guildid` supposed to be a variable holding `temp1`? Don't put it in quotes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I kinda messed it up. It's correctly edited now. And also, no `data["temp1"][temp2]` doesn't return "!", but an error `Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Why are you using a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary?

Comment: After reading your question several times, I'm unclear on what you are asking. When you say "return", do you mean that this code is in a function and you literally need to add a `return` statement? Or do you mean something else? You say there will be more dictionaries "like this one"...like which one? Do you mean the `data` dict? Will you [edit] your question with a fuller example that shows how you want to work with multiple dicts?

Comment: You need to loop through `data["temp1"]` to find the element with `temp2` in the keys.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are talking about, the data dictionary is the only thing in the json file right now.

Comment: @Mbuxiq I think Barmar is referring to the list nested at the key `"temp1"`.

Comment: Oh, I've changed it to data = {"temp1": "!", "temp2" : "123" }, since maybe making a list is unnecessary. This works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    data = {
>        "temp1": [
>            {"temp2": "!"},
>            {"temp3": "123"}
>        ]
>    }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `data["temp1"]["temp2"]` doesn't return `"!"`, but an error `Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

If you are asking how to solve this problem, I suggest you break what you are trying to do in separate pieces:

```
print(data["temp1"])
```

This will print a list. The reason you get an error is because you attempt to index that list with a string, but you must use an integer instead:

```
print(data["temp1"][0])
```

Now this will print out the first dict in the list which you can then index with a string:

```
print(data["temp1"][0]["temp2"])
```

As Barmar posted in his answer, you may need to loop over the list given by `data["temp1"]` to do what you need. Your question doesn't include enough details for me to recommend if that's the correct approach.

The key thing here is to follow the shape of the data and index it appropriately. As I show above, it often helps to add one index at a time. You should even consider assigning each piece to a variable.

Comment: Yeah, this works. It feels like a basic thing to ask, so I'll might research more before diving head straight in. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @Mbuxiq If you still need some help, see my longer comment under your question where I ask for some clarification on your problem.

Comment: I think I'm good. I am sorry that the title and the question itself isn't exactly saying what I want to do. But as I said, I'm still new to this and json is my first experience with some form of database, and I started like 5 hours ago. So I'll probably read some documents and/or some comments on Stack Overflow to understand json better.

Comment: @Mbuxiq Asking the right question is a skill in and of itself. JSON itself isn't complicated. It's just dictionaries and lists nested inside each other. You just need to keep track of what kind of thing you have after each index operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to find `temp2` in the list of dictionaries.

```
with open("./Config/test.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for item in data["temp1"]:
    if "temp2" in item:
        print(item["temp2"])
```

it would be easier if you had a single dictionary rather than a list of dictionaries with different keys, e.g.

```
data = {
    "temp1": {
        "temp2": "!",
        "temp3": "123"
    }
}
```